# Remove repeated adjacent words in a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

word document may contain repeated adjacent words. can there be a vba macro code to retain single occurrence, and delete the repeat.

eg,

He is is doing well.

should change to

He is doing well.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't try it because office.live.com doesn't seem to support wildcards, but you can try this:

In `Find and Replace` > `Replace` > check `Use wildcards` and in the `Find what:` enter "`(<*>) <\1>`" and click `Find Next` to see if that matches the two words. If it does, enter "`\1`" in `Replace with:` and click `Replace All` to see if everything works as expected. If it does, you can `Record Macro` of those steps and check the generated code.

The above expression should also find repeating numbers like `a123 a123`. If you don't want that, you can try this expression in the `Find what:`

```
(<[A-Za-z]{1,}>) \1[!A-Za-z]
```

from http://www.louiseharnbyproofreader.com/blog-the-proofreaders-parlour/proofreading-in-word-one-of-my-favourite-findreplace-strings

Comment: THANK YOU BROTHER, Worked Perfectly! GOD BLESS YOU!